# Is this possible in ASP.NET? Change data on a page without reloading page

Tags: asp.net, pageload

I want a table in the page to be filled with the data that corresponds with a picture on the page. The user has to click the picture that he wants more information about. The way i have done this is making the images into image-Buttons, Make the button store a session variable and redirect back to the same page, then the session variable is read and used to fill the table. Is it possible to get the same results without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I can guess that you're using webforms.

Yes, it's possible in ASP.NET, take a look at [**UpdatePanel**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control, it does exactly what you want.